# SET /p is not centralized in Batch. Problems with whitespaces

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This is my TXT :

```
echo         x  1.   Enter               x  
echo         x  2.   Leave               x
echo         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo:

set /p Menu=               Enter number {1,2}: 

if not '%Menu%'=='' set Menu=%Menu:~0,1%
if '%Menu%'=='1' goto ConvM
```

My txt is converted to *.bat at home and, when the batch runs, the center portion of the phrase "Enter number {1,2}:" is positioned exactly in the middle of the delimiter "x". Result as shown below :

```
     x  1.   Enter               x  
     x  2.   Leave               x
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

          Enter number {1,2}:
```

My txt is converted to *.bat at the company where I work and, when the batch runs, it shows something offset as shown below :

```
     x  1.   Enter               x  
     x  2.   Leave               x
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Enter number {1,2}:
```

I converted my txt also to CMD but the result is the same. At home I have a Windows XP and at work I have Windows 7.
What should I do to have the "Enter number {1,2}:" centralized with the "x" in any computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Windows 7 (and I think Vista as well) ignores leading white space in a `SET /P` prompt. Whitespace characters include space, tab, and non-breaking space (0xFF).

The solution is not intuitive, but it is simple. Just prefix your prompt with a backspace (0x08) character. The code below programmatically defines a variable containing a backspace character. It is then easy to include it in any propmpt as needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Define a BS variable containing a backspace (0x08) character
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H & echo on & for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%A"

echo         x  1.   Enter               x
echo         x  2.   Leave               x
echo         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo:

set /p Menu=%BS%               Enter number {1,2}:
```

Normally a backspace will cause the line cursor to back up one position, and then the next character will overwrite what was there. But since the prompt always starts at the first position, there is no room to back up one. The backspace effectively does nothing accept allow for leading white space in your prompt :-)

You can put another character in front of the backspace if you want, but it is not needed. The backspace will back the line cursor up one position, and then your desired prompt will overwrite the unwanted character.

```
set /p Menu=x%BS%               Enter number {1,2}:
```

**EDIT - Here is an explanation of the `FOR /F` line that defines the BS variable**

The `PROMPT` command controls the text that appears as a prefix of each line of output when ECHO is ON. By default it is the current directory followed by the `>` character.

Using `PROMPT $H` causes the prompt to be `<backspace><space><backspace>`. So a command like `REM` will result in output of `<backspace><space><backspace>REM`.

There is a string of commands on one line that is executed. Normally commands are not echoed if they appear on the same line that issues the ECHO ON. The exception to that rule is any command that appears as part of a FOR DO clause *is* echoed. That is why the REM command is "executed" within a FOR loop - so we get the output of the REM command.

The entire string of commands is executed within an outer `FOR /F` loop. The string is enclosed in single quotes to tell `FOR /F` to execute a command. Within the single quotes the string is enclosed within double quotes. The double quotes protect the command concatenation `&` operator. Normally a string of commands cannot be enclosed in double quotes. But it works in this case because of how `FOR /F` works. The commands are executed implicitly via `CMD /C "command string"`. So it is perfectly acceptable in this case to use the double quotes.

If double quotes are not used then the `&` characters must be escaped with `^`:

```
('prompt $H ^& echo on ^& for %%B in (1) do rem')
```

Finally, since the default `FOR /F DELIMS` is `<tab><space>`, the output of the REM command will be parsed into tokens, and only the first token is preserved. The end result is BS value consisting of a single `<backspace>` character.

Comment: Yep, it is working! Could you possibly explain the "for /f" line in detail? It would be nice to learn that. I have also tried another thing as echoing the phrase "                  Enter number {1,2}:" with whitespaces and let the "set /p Menu=", void like that. It also worked! Is it a problem to leave the (set /p menu=) equal to nothing ?

Comment: @user1573858 - It all depends on where you want your input cursor - to the right of your prompt, or on the next line on the far left? My answer puts it to the right, your solution puts it below. I don't have time now to provide a detailed explanation of the FOR /F line. I'll try to remember to get to it later.

Comment: OK. Waiting then for the explanation in detail. Kind regards !

Comment: @user1573858 - See my edited answer for an explanation of the FOR /F line.

Comment: Just great! Is it possible that you give me your email? Sometimes I did get stuck in questions that I posted and had no reply for a long time. In case that occurs again, I would email you so as you could take a peek on the link. It seems that you are part of a very selected group of people who really masters the DOS language. Thank you for the explanations. Kind regards [maleck25@hotmail.com]

Comment: @Adriano : Some time ago you added a comment on this post which was nice but you have erased it later on. You added a set /p option that the user could not type in any letter or symbol, exept that specified in the set /p (lets say for example the numbers 1 and 2 are valid). If anything else was typed (as 3, *, €, p etc), the batch would do nothing and it reacts as if other symbols or letters were locked. Could you post that again, please?

Comment: @user1573858 it was another command: choice /c 12 /m "bla bla bla